# git how to delete mysterious file still present after resetting the entire branch

Tags: git, github

Hmm, so I have a project in my branch that contained a very large file which github rejected on push:

```
remote: error: File burorevise/bootstrap/img/imgs.psd is 139.42 MB; this     exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To git@github.com:vomc/privat.git
! [remote rejected] branch0.3 -> branch0.3 (pre-receive hook declined)
```

I have seen several posts about this issue and they all suggested rebasing or resetting to `HEAD` all of which I have tried, including doing a force removal in git and then doing a `git clean -f -d <path>` for the entire directory as well.

Now when I do git status, I am getting a message that:
    On branch branch0.3
    Your branch is ahead of 'origin/branch0.3' by 6 commits.
    (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

And I see no trace of my project and the large file that was causing this error as I have deleted them all. But of course the `ahead by 6 commits` indicates that it is still somewhere. So now when I do a `git push` of course its still trying to push this file that is gone from the harddrive.

Is there a quick fix for this? Or is it best to just make a new branch and nuke this entire situation?

THanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you do anything I tell you, start off a new branch at `HEAD`, just in case. It's going to allow you to abandon all changes, should something go wrong.

The classic way of dealing with this would be to make an **interactive rebase** of the commits starting at the one which introduced the file. So say you are on the relevant branch (and this would have to be done for **all branches** where the chain of unfortunate commits is present!).

So say the change was done 6 commits ago (at commit `HEAD~5`). We have to base our changes on the previous commit (the `HEAD` of your remote branch), so we execute:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~6
```

Now you have to `edit` the commit which introduced the file in question. You do that as if you were amending the commit:

```
git rm <file>
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

This should remove the file from your history. If there's a single commit which introduced the file, you can also delete it instead of editing it (by removing the line with the commit itself).

If you bump into problems with merging (the file changed, and the change was committed later on), deal with it just as you would if it was a commit which introduced the file (the sequence above).

I am not sure about it, but you *might* have to run `git gc` to get rid of old objects (`push` should hopefully do that for you when packing, I think).

edit: Please note that the above method **changes history of your branch** and you should not try doing that with commits which have been already pushed to or pulled by some remote repository (for example Github, or your co-workers' local repos). It's going to make your collaborators hate you with passion, since they won't be able to contribute their work and would have to forcefully overwrite their local branches OR you won't be able to push your changes.